# TableLayout width not setting

Tags: android, tablelayout

I'm trying to design a layout to hold a textview an edit text and some buttons. My problem is whenever the title i set goes over a certain length it disappears and doesnt display and I'm also having trouble with the button, the content isnt wrapping its always alot longer than it should be, can anyone see why?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

      <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

      <TableRow
         android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/frst1"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="Title:"
                 android:textSize="15sp" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnwhichcncl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `android:id="@+id/frst1"` and `android:id="@+id/btnwhichcncl"` are supposed to be the first columns of the table both would be necessarily of same width as due to property of table.

Could you explain what view you are supposed(desired) to get and actual problem.

Comment: The cancel button should only be as wide as the word cancel inside it, instead it extends and is alot longer.

Comment: but your first row first column is textView if it increases the button will also increase as it's the same column of table,,

Comment: If you really want that drop the table idea,, or simply surround button with a Linear Layout and then Table Row etc

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting your TableLayout  width to fill_parent? also, try setting the rows to fill_parent or match_parent

Comment: neither of those suggestions helped.

Comment: Also, set the button and textview to fill_parent.